# Разработка простого учебного web приложения на Django с использование Docker (docker-compose)

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

Мне хотелось бы попрактиковаться в Django и Docker, создав небольшое приложение, которое разрасталось по мере осваивания технологий - так сказать учебный полигон для набивания шишек. Я планирую пока что собрать простую систему из двух docker контейнеров (docker-compose) для Postgres и Django. Позже перенести frontend например на Angular (с отдельным контейнером).

Какие пробемы у меня могут возникнуть (я уже запускал тестовые связки Django-Postgres в Docker) в процессе разрастания проекта? Пропадут ли данные из базы (пускай и заполненные "рыбой") при добавлении нового сервиса в docker-compose и т. д. Есть ли не очевидные подводные камни?

Вопрос несколько абстрактный, и за это можно попинать, но мне бы хотелось понять общую картину, перед тем как решать конкретные возникающие проблемы.

Comment: если проект будет разрастаться возможно вы натолкнётесь на проблему отсутствия свободного места на диске, решается она покупкой более большого диска или удалением "старых" данных, можно сделать руками, а можно утилиту скачать... вообщем ждём конкретных вопросов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вижу такой процесс обучения c учетом:

> я уже запускал тестовые связки Django-Postgres в Docker)

**Стараться использовать** alpine based images

```
FROM python:3.7.0-alpine3.8

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN apk --update add --virtual .base build-base git && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    rm requirements.txt && \
    apk del .base && \
    addgroup -g 1001 -S example && \
    adduser -D -S -u 1000 -G example -h /home/example \
      example && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/man /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
        /var/cache/apk/* /var/log/* ~/.cache

COPY . /home/example/
RUN chown -R example:example /home/example

USER example
WORKDIR /home/example

CMD python server.py
```

*Монтирование проекта в `/home/*` даст преимущество для разработки таких как история python, sh, которая будет в корне проекта (их добавим в .dockerignore, .gitignore)*

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  example
    image: example-development
    command: sh -c './wait-for pg.example_net:5432 -- python server.py'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    networks:
      - net
    volumes:
      - .:/home/example
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - pg
      - example__migrator
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
```

**Собирать** только с нужными файлами c `.dockeringore`

```
*
!src
```

**Добавить** reverse proxy (nginx) и понять как работают `bridge`

Даже без `angular` будет профит для отдачи статики.

При добавлении `angular`сделать через [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

```
FROM node:8.15.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /app/
RUN npm build

FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY --from=0 /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

> Пропадут ли данные из базы (пускай и заполненные "рыбой")

**Использовать** [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

```
pg:
  image: postgres:10.0-alpine
  environment:
    PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_data
  volumes:
    - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_data
  networks:
    - net
```

**Советую** делать миграции отдельным контейнером '__migrator' (p.s. deploy опция для docker-swarm)

```
example__migrator:
  command: sh -c './wait-for pg:5432 -- python manage.py migrate'
  deploy:
    mode: replicated
    restart_policy:
      condition: none
```

Малость расписал про `development` окружение. Как только нужно будет развернуть приложение и поддерживать добавляется `docker-swarm` (идеально для одного сервера или при возможности можно масштабироваться в кластер).

Тут уже много подводных камней. Можно ознакомиться с моим [проектом автоматизации деплоя](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-repo-for-startup).

Comment: А почему вы рекомендуете использовать alpine образы?

Comment: Меньше весят, соотвественно быстрее билды и деплои. Плюс  меньше дыр в безопастности.